# Passing a string to SelectParameter function asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, sql

So it has been a very long time since I wrote an ASP page. In fact it was Classic ASP and now I am struggling to catch up with the new .NET version.

My issue, I want to search a database for rows that are for the current week only. It should show rows from Mon thru Fri of the current week no matter what day of the current week I am viewing the page.

I began with the below code which gives me the two dates to insert into my `SqlDataSource` "Where" string.

```
  Dim Mon As DateTime
  Dim Fri As DateTime
  Dim daysDiff As Integer
  daysDiff = 2 - Weekday(DateTime.Today)
  Mon = DateAdd("d", daysDiff, DateTime.Today)
  Fri = DateAdd("d", 4, Mon)
```

Now my issue is I don't know how to grab the values of "Mon" and "Fri" to insert it into the ASP:SqlDataSource SelectCommand function

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [Concerts] WHERE ShowDate >= MON AND ShowDate <= Fri" >
```

I need it to resolve into:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT * From [Concerts] WHERE ShowDate >= 09/12/2011 AND ShowDate <= 09/16/2011">
```

Your help is appreciated as I have been at this for a couple of days trying to get through this one thing which should be fairly simple to you experts out there.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to set the `DefaultValue` of the parameter that you are using in your `SqlDataSource`.

Example:

```
<asp:sqlDataSource ID="ConcertsSqlDataSource" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT * From [Concerts] WHERE ShowDate >= @StartDate AND ShowDate <= @EndDate"

  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>"
  OnInserted="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource_OnInserted"
  RunAt="server">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:sqlDataSource>
```

Code behind (this is C# but should be similar in VB.NET)

```
ConcertsSqlDataSource.SelectParameters["StartDate"].DefaultValue = Mon.ToString();
ConcertsSqlDataSource.SelectParameters["EndDate"].DefaultValue = Friday.ToString();
```

After that you can either `DataBind()` the control you've attached it to or handle the results in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following..
Edit your ASPX page.
Make sure your SELECT Command reads as follows:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Concerts] WHERE (([ShowDate] &gt; @MON) AND ([ShowDate ] &lt; @FRI))">
      <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="MON" DefaultValue="" Type="DateTime"  />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FRI" DefaultValue="" Type="DateTime"  />
      </SelectParameters>
```

now in your code behind you can add the following..

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["MON"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(Mon);
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["FRI"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(Fri);
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Generally speaking I stay away from SqlDataSource and use DataSets-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

Comment: How would I generate the same results using the DataSet.  Sorry I am a real newbie and working my way to learning.